# Ant profile deployment - You cannot deploy to a required field Object_Name__c.Field_Name__c

Tags: deployment, profile, ant

I am getting the below error when I am trying to deploy a new profile:

You cannot deploy to a required field Object_Name__c.Field_Name__c.

I saw the solution posted here: [Force.com IDE profile deployment - You cannot deploy to a required field Object_Name__c.Field_Name__c](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36391/force-com-ide-profile-deployment-you-cannot-deploy-to-a-required-field-object)

But I have used an existing .profile file and I am trying to give read only access to all the fields and objects for an app.

There are a lot of objects and fields and hence not able to detect the required fields and remove them from the file.

Any solution for this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is the answer to this question:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36391/force-com-ide-profile-deployment-you-cannot-deploy-to-a-required-field-object

Answer (score 6):

"Since API version 30.0 a change set or ant deployment will fail if a field that is required in the field definition is included in a profile or permission set that is being deployed.

If you create a new custom field and check 'Required', Field Level Security automatically becomes 'Visible' for all profiles. Similarly, if you edit the definition of a custom field which is not visible to all profiles and check 'Required' then it automatically becomes visible to all profiles. Therefore there is no need to reference it in a permission set. Try it!"

It means, that you need to remove from profile metadata fieldPermissions of this field.